# Using RecyclerView and getting information from Web services but not displaying answers and I'm not getting any errors WHY?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<BookData>> {
    private static final String GOOGLEBOOKURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=search+terms";
    private static final String TAG = "Mainactivity";
  private   RecyclerView recyclerview;
    private RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter;
    private static final int BOOK_LOADER_ID = 1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayList<BookData> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(this,arrayList);
        recyclerview = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
       recyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerview.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);

        LoaderManager loaderManager = getSupportLoaderManager();
        Log.i(TAG, "Now calling initLoader");
        loaderManager.initLoader(BOOK_LOADER_ID, null, this);


        DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(this,DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);
        recyclerview.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);


    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Loader<List<BookData>> onCreateLoader(int id, @Nullable Bundle args) {
        Log.i(TAG,"Problem with onCreateloader");
        return new BookLoader(MainActivity.this,GOOGLEBOOKURL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(@NonNull Loader<List<BookData>> loader, List<BookData> data) {
        recyclerAdapter.clear();
        if (data != null && !data.isEmpty()) {
            recyclerAdapter.addAll(data);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(@NonNull Loader<List<BookData>> loader) {
        recyclerAdapter.clear();
        Log.i(TAG, "Now loader is resetting");
    }
}
```

Adapter

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<BookData> mArrayList;
    Context mContext;

    public RecyclerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<BookData> arrayList) {
        mArrayList = arrayList;
        mContext = context;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
       View v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.rowrepresent,parent,false);
       viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        BookData currentPosition = mArrayList.get(position);
      //  holder.authorname.setText(currentPosition.getAuthorName());
        holder.titlename.setText(currentPosition.getTitleName());
      //  holder.mImageView.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(currentPosition.getImage()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mArrayList.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        ImageView mImageView;
        TextView titlename,authorname;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
          //  mImageView = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.bookImage);
           titlename=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleName);
          //  authorname=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.authorName);
        }
    }
    public void clear() {
        if (mArrayList != null && !mArrayList.isEmpty()) {
            int size = mArrayList.size();
            mArrayList.clear();
            notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, size);
        }
    }

    public void addAll(List<BookData> data){
          mArrayList.addAll(data);
    }
}
```

Network

```
public class Network {
    private static final String TAG = "Network";

    public static ArrayList<BookData> extractbooksfromurl(String requesturl){
        ArrayList<BookData> BookDetails;
        URL url = createUrl(requesturl);

        String jsonresponse = null;
        try {
            jsonresponse = makeHttprequest(url);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error closing input stream", e);
        }

        BookDetails = extractInfojson(jsonresponse);
        return BookDetails;
    }

    private static URL createUrl(String requestUrl) {
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(requestUrl);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "The problem with URL", e);
        }
        return url;
    }

    private static String makeHttprequest(URL url) throws IOException {
        String jsonresponse = "";
        if (url == null) {
            return jsonresponse;
        }
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(1000);
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(1500);
            urlConnection.connect();
            if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                jsonresponse = readfromstream(inputStream);
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error response code:" + urlConnection.getResponseCode());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "problem with MakeHttprequest method", e);
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (inputStream != null) {
                inputStream.close();
            }
        }
        return jsonresponse;
    }

    private static String readfromstream(InputStream inputStream)throws IOException {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        if (inputStream!= null){
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
            try {
                String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                while (line!=null ){
                    output.append(line);
                    line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG,"Problem in readfromstream method",e);
            }
        } return output.toString();

    }
    public  static ArrayList<BookData> extractInfojson(String bookListData){
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(bookListData)){
            return  null;
        }
        ArrayList<BookData> arrayListnew = new ArrayList<>();
        String authorsName = "";
        String title;
        String images;
        try {
            JSONObject jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(bookListData);
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonRootObject.optJSONArray("item");
            if (jsonArray != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.optJSONObject(i);
                    JSONObject volumeinfo = jsonObject.getJSONObject("volumeInfo");
                  /* JSONArray authors_list ;
                   if (volumeinfo.has("authors")){
                      authors_list = volumeinfo.getJSONArray("authors");
                       for (int y=0;y<authors_list.length();y++)
                           authorsName = authors_list.getString(y);
                   }else{
                       authorsName ="No Author";
                   }
                    title = volumeinfo.getString("title").toString();
                    JSONObject image = volumeinfo.getJSONObject("imageLinks");
                           images = image.getString("thumbnail").toString();*/
                   title = volumeinfo.getString("title").toString();
                    arrayListnew.add(new BookData(title));
                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG,"problem in parsing the data",e);
        }
    return arrayListnew;
    }


}
```

Logcats

```
2020-11-21 11:27:29.407 12457-12457/com.example.booklistapp I/Mainactivity: Now calling initLoader
2020-11-21 11:27:29.407 12457-12457/com.example.booklistapp I/Mainactivity: Problem with onCreateloader
2020-11-21 11:27:29.412 12457-12457/com.example.booklistapp I/BookLoader: Now onStartLoading method
2020-11-21 11:27:29.417 12457-12472/com.example.booklistapp I/BookLoader: Now LoadinBackground method
2020-11-21 11:27:29.426 12457-12472/com.example.booklistapp D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2020-11-21 11:27:29.496 12457-12473/com.example.booklistapp I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2020-11-21 11:27:29.496 12457-12473/com.example.booklistapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
2020-11-21 11:27:29.496 12457-12473/com.example.booklistapp W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2020-11-21 11:27:29.496 12457-12473/com.example.booklistapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
2020-11-21 11:27:29.575 12457-12473/com.example.booklistapp D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x9b827520: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
2020-11-21 11:27:29.688 12457-12473/com.example.booklistapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9b827520: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9b89ad10)
2020-11-21 11:27:29.733 12457-12473/com.example.booklistapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9b827520: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9b89ad10)
```

SomeBody help me in this one,I'm not getting any errors but Still answers not displaying ? why?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `Recyclerview` adapter  `addAll` method, after adding to the array make a call to [notifyDataSetChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged())

like this:

```
public void addAll(List<BookData> data) {
      mArrayList.addAll(data);
      notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**Update:**

As per comments the code works when you use dummy data and this points to another issue in your network request logic.
You can debug your application by placing various breakpoints in methods or on lines of code to help ascertain where your codes logic is not functioning as expected. https://developer.android.com/studio/debug
Any other questions you have should be in a new question as this one is really solved.

Id also suggest using a library like [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley) which will greatly simplify your network requests. Specifically see [Making a standard request in Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request)

Comment: It's still same, not showing answers in recyclerView

Comment: Can you please tell me whether addall method is correct or not, i added above code which you said but still answers are not showing

Comment: Make sure your `onLoadFinished` method is being called and ensure that you have data and its not empty or null. You can manually test it by simply calling `addAll` method yourself with some dummy data.

Comment: public void addAll(List<BookData> data){
        Log.d(TAG, "addAll: Now addall is executing");
          mArrayList.add(new BookData("WWEEE"));
         notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

Comment: I have passed dummy data and i called it but still answers is not showing, can you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: What you did is not what I meant.... I mean in your `onCreate` method comment out this line `loaderManager.initLoader(BOOK_LOADER_ID)` and then on the last line of the `onCreate` do this `recyclerAdapter.addAll(new BookData("test"));` don't forget to delete the other changes you did except for the `notifyDataSetChanged()` of course leave that in there

Comment: initLoader asking three arguments but here one argument only and addAll () is not executing

Comment: Comment out the initLoader line. Put // in front of it we don't care about the line....

Comment: And at the end of the `onCreate` method put this line `recyclerAdapter.addAll(new BookData("test"));`

Comment: This one is working which you said above, Now what I should do?

Comment: So the problem is not the `recyclerAdapter.addAll` anymore. That is my point. I helped you fix that in the above answer. I'd suggest marking this as solved and creating a new question. But if you put a breakpoint in the `onLoadFinished` method and hover over `data` I think you will find the data is empty or null so its never calling `recyclerAdapter.addAll`

Comment: Thanks for helping me but how can i find where is the problem ? In URL there is a data but here displaying empty

Comment: You can debug your app, by placing breakpoints inside various methods you are interested in and you can step over or into each line of code/method until you find where your code isn't working https://developer.android.com/studio/debug

Comment: Updated my answer as well. I'd suggest marking this as solved and any other issue you find by debugging can be a new question

Comment: Thanks bro for replying

Comment: @MadhanMohan Always happy to help

Comment: I thought I'm giving so much trouble to you

Comment: @MadhanMohan Lol na, its part of development and learning. Happy coding until we meet again!

Comment: Still i'm not able to find it bro do you know any Google Book api's link it here I don't know